# OnsenUI : Tabbar with badger notification

Tags: onsen-ui

I have this:

```
<ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
    <ons-tabbar-item icon="search" label="Buscar" page="page2.html" active="true"><div class="badge-notification"><span class="notification">1</span></div></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item icon="star-o" label="Revisões" page="page2.html">XXXXXXX<span class="notification">9</span></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item icon="tag" label="Combinações" page="page2.html"><span class="notification">9</span></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item icon="comments" label="Conversas" page="page2.html"><span class="notification">9</span></ons-tabbar-item> </ons-tabbar>
```

How I can put a badge-notification working? Like show (1) upside the button "Search"?... I can make this in CSS... But, i lost the use of tab-bar...

```
<div class="tab-bar">
<label class="tab-bar__item">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-screen2" data-role="none" checked>
    <button class="tab-bar__button" data-role="none" >
        <i class="tab-bar__icon fa fa-4x fa-search"></i>
        <div class="tab-bar__label">Buscar</div>
    </button>
</label>
<label class="tab-bar__item">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-screen2" data-role="none">
    <button class="tab-bar__button" data-role="none" >
    <i class="tab-bar__icon fa fa-4x fa-star-o"></i>
    <div class="tab-bar__label">Revisões</div>
    <span class="notification">8</span>
    </button>
</label>
<label class="tab-bar__item">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-screen2" data-role="none">
    <button class="tab-bar__button" data-role="none" >
    <i class="tab-bar__icon fa fa-4x fa-tag"></i>
    <div class="tab-bar__label">Combinações</div>
    <span class="notification">9</span>
    </button>
</label>
<label class="tab-bar__item">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-screen2" data-role="none" >
    <button class="tab-bar__button" data-role="none" >
    <i class="tab-bar__icon fa fa-4x fa-comments"></i>
    <div class="tab-bar__label">Bate-Papo</div>
    <span class="notification">10</span>
    </button>
</label>
</div>
```

Anyone know too where I can find a good documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot add badge to the tab item for the current version of OnsenUI. We will consider putting this in the next release.

However, it's possible if you use the CSS as shown in ur code above. But you can't use the function and transition of the OnsenUI framework anymore since now it's just simply OnsenUI CSS components. Therefore, you will need to write your own necessary function using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted your question, but since I recently had to deal with the exact same problem, here's my solution.

Onsen modifies the DOM for each `ons-tab` element.  So, simple DOM modification (jQuery or not) didn't work because I couldn't reliably detect when the tabbar has been completely initialized.
What I did is I created a controller that sets up a function to execute every second (`changeNotifications`).  In this function I add the notification **once** I have detected that tab bar has been initialized.

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ons-tabbar var="tabbar" modifier="ios">
    <ons-tab icon="ion-email" id="inbox-tab" label="{{ 'Inbox' | translate }}" page="inbox.html" active="true">
  <!-- more tabs -->
</body>
```

In `MainCtrl.js` I have my "main" controller"

```
function _MainCtrl($scope,) {
  function changeNotifications() {
    var inboxTab = $('#inbox-tab');
    if (!inboxTab.length) {
      return; // not initialized yet
    }
    var notif = $('#inbox-notification');
    if (!notif.length) {
      $('#inbox-tab > button').append(
        $('<div class="notification tabbar-notification" id="inbox-notification">5</div>'));
      notif = $('#inbox-notification');
    }

    var numWhatever = 5;
    if (numWhatever == 0) {
      notif.remove();
    } else {
      notif.text(numWhatever);
    }
  }

  function initNotifications() {
    ons.ready(function() {
      setInterval(changeNotifications, 1000);
    });
  }
  initNotifications();
}
```

In addition to Onsen's `notification` style, I am adding the following by means of the `tabbar-notification` CSS class:

```
.tabbar-notification {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -44px;
  min-width: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```